# Добавление точки к адресу сайта

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, ссылки

#### Описание

Скопировал ссылку сайта из текста, случайно скопировав точку вместе со ссылкой - [https://ru.stackoverflow.com.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com./)
Открылся сайт как для нового пользователя:

[image]

При этом у меня аккаунт подключен:

[image]

---

#### Вопрос

Это что за находка у меня? 
Оно просто открывает сайт в режиме "гость", или же есть какие-то специфичные функции?

Comment: [Why does putting a dot after the URL remove login information?](https://superuser.com/a/1467966/761205)

Comment: фактически это два разных домена, и информация об авторизации только для одного. google и youtube например делают редирект с адреса с точкой в конце и у них такой проблемы нет :)

Comment: @Grundy, с тех пор, как ютьюбу стали добавлять точку чтобы смотреть без рекламы - до этого не делали.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

При добавлении точки меняется top-level домен с `.com` на `.`. Поскольку домену `com` в обоих случаях адрес выдаётся одинаково (я в этой теме не очень разбираюсь, но идея такая), сайт продолжает открываться, но для браузера домены разные, поэтому сайты, открытые с точкой и без точки, не могут взаимодействовать между собой в плане кук и хранилищ, но могут что-то запрашивать через [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).